# gem install eventmachine fails, using rvm

Tags: 13.10, compiling, rvm, gem

Ubuntu 13.10 64bit,

```
ruby 2.1.1 
rvm 1.25.24   
gem 2.2.2
```

from log file:

```
compiling pipe.cpp                                                                                                                          
linking shared-object rubyeventmachine.so                                                                                                   
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libssl.a(s23_srvr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object;      recompile with -fPIC                                                                                                                        
/usr/local/lib/libssl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value                                                                                    
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status                                                                                                  
make: *** [rubyeventmachine.so] Error 1                                                                                                     

make failed, exit code 2
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like this issue on Github: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/392

The basic solution was recompiling ssl with shared, details are inside the link.